# Getting the lengths of each word in its String parameter

Tags: java, strings

Is this a smart method?

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> getWordLengths( String s )
{

    String str = " " + s + " ";

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for ( int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++ )
    {
        if ( str.charAt(i) == ' ' )
        {
            for ( int j = i+1; j < str.length() ; j++)
            {
                if ( str.charAt(j) == ' ')
                {
                    list.add( j - i - 1 );
                    j = str.length();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return list;        
}
```

Sample output:

```
System.out.println( getWordLengths("This is really easy")); 

[4, 2, 6, 4]
```

so it worked.

We are only allowed to use length and `charAt` from the `String` class.

Comment: Something I'm seeing: all solutions would fail with `"This_is__not__so_easy"` (`_` are spaces). That is simply fixed by adding `if (s.charAt(i) == ' ' && count > 0) {` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**:

```
    String s = "This is really easy";

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            System.out.println("count is " + count);
            count = 0;
        } else {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("count is " + count);
```

**Output**:

```
count is 4
count is 2
count is 6
count is 4
```

**Explanation**:

keep counting the length of each word till you see a blank. As soon as, you see a blank, write down a length current word and set count to zero and make it ready for new word. At the end, you should write down the length the last word outside of the for loop.

**Note:** Big o of my code is n , yet your is n^2; therefore, my method is faster than your approach.

Comment: Does not produce the requested output.  For a trivial fix consider `System.out.print(count + ", ");`

Answer (score 2):

```
//only allowed to use length and charAt from string class
public static ArrayList<Integer> getWordLengths( String s )
{
    String str = s + " ";

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int count = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++ )
    {
        if ( str.charAt(i) == ' ' )
        {
            list.add(count);
            count = 0;   
        }
        else
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return list;        
}
```

Output:

```
[4, 2, 6, 4]
```

As long as the length and charAt limitations only apply to string methods and not to use of a List this should be fine.  Just because you need to count more than one thing doesn't mean you need more than one loop.

Answer (score 1):

There is a split method for `String` that will split your string into an array of `String`s based on the value you give it.

So in this case you could use spaces:

```
String[] arr = s.split(" ");
int[] result = arr.length;
for(int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    result[x] = arr[x].length();
}
```

Since you can only use length and `charAt`, you could also do it this way, which is faster. `list` will contain the lengths of each word. `prev` keeps track of the start of the word you're on, so you can use it to subtract when you find the next space. You have to add 1 to it each time so that it will be on the beginning of the word instead of the space.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int prev = 0;
for(int x = 0; x <= line.length(); x++) {
    if(x == line.length() || line.charAt(x) == ' ') {
        list.add(x - prev);
        prev = x + 1;
    }
}
```

Check out the [`String` class API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)! If you want to look into split more, [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs302/examples/Parsing/parseString.html) are some good examples!

Comment: thank you, it is nice.. but there is a note: we are only allowed to use charAt and length method from string class :(

Comment: @haley if you clarify "different parts **based on what you tell it**." better, I gladly vote u up

Comment: @KickButtowski I'll do that!

Comment: @cihangirND hope my answer helps.

Comment: @cihangirND let me know if the edit I made helps! :)

Comment: yes it worked but one problem. [4, 2, 6]
it does not print last one.. i think we need one more space after string

Comment: Sorry about that! I changed the for loop to go <= to the length and I added a condition to the if statement. This won't cause an index out of bounds because the if statement will short circuit before it tries to get the character at line.length().

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't allowed to use ArrayList, or if you just think [tail recursion is cool](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/1270:_Functional), you can do it this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println( getWordLengths("This is really easy") ); 
}

public static String getWordLengths( String s )
{
    return "[" + getWordLengthsRecursively(s, 0, 0, 0)  + "]";  
}

public static String getWordLengthsRecursively( String s, int i,  int start, int end )
{
    // Last word 
    if ( s.length() == i)
    {
        return "" + (end - start); 
    }

    // Found a word  
    if ( s.charAt(i) == ' ' )
    {
        return (end - start) + ", " + getWordLengthsRecursively(s, ++i, i, i);
    }

    // Word not found.  Move to next character.
    else
    {
        return getWordLengthsRecursively(s, ++i, start, ++end);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[4, 2, 6, 4]
```

I like it when I don't have to import anything.  Don't you?